# How to get the text given in a text box through web driver

Tags: webdriver

How to get the text given in a text box through web driver.
I am aware the the given text will be stored as value in that field.But how to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

- Stored as value : `webdriver.findElement(By...).getAttribute("value"))`
- Stored as enclosing text: `webdriver.findElement(By...).getText())`

Comment: I tried with this but empty space is getting printed..how can i print the value...

Comment: Can you post the HTML section of the checkbox? And also the selector you use.

Comment: The checkbox form, how does it look like? And the selector, or xPath, whatever you are putting instead of "By...".